# Executing the query using bq command line in Google Big Query

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery

I execute a query using the below Python script and the table gets populated with 2,564,691 rows. When I run the same query using Google Big Query console, it returns 17,379,353 rows (query is as-is). I was wondering whether there is some issue with the below script. Not sure whether --replace in bq query replaces the past result set instead of appending to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
dateToday =  (time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
dateToday1 = dateToday.replace('/','')

commandStr = "type C:\Users\query.txt | bq query --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table table:dataset1_%s -n 1" %(dateToday1)
```

Comment: If you are willing to share job IDs for the two jobs, we (BigQuery team) can investigate further to see what might be different between the two queries.

Comment: Job Id of query that is run through Web UI: red-road-574:bquijob_64bd407c_1560f071d85

Comment: Can you also share the ID for the query via the command line?

Comment: @DannyKitt: The job id for query via command line is bqjob_r5790ceea_000001560fdd5e9b_1

Comment: I looked at your job details: those two queries are not exactly the same.  The structures of the two queries are the same, but bqjob_r5790ceea_000001560fdd5e9b_1 references the 20160721 tables via `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (as it was run on 20160721), while red-road-574:bquijob_64bd407c_1560f071d85 references the 20160719 tables explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In the Web UI you can use Query History option to navigate to respective queries.
After you locate them  - you can expand respective entries and see what exactly query was executed
I am more than sure that just comparing query texts you will see source of "discrepancy" right away!

> added

In Query History - not only you can see Query Text, but also all configuration properties that were used for respective query - like `Write Preference` for example and others. So even if query text the same you can see potential difference in configuration that will give you a clue

Comment: The query is exactly the same. The script I  mentioned above runs every 10 minutes and populates the table. When I run the script for yesterday's date, it returns the same number of rows. But when i check the number of rows in yesterday's table (that was populated by the script yesterday), there is a huge difference. Thats why I wonder whether --replace makes any changes.

Comment: See Danny Kitt's comment to the question: They are not the same query (same structure, different tables scanned)